# Showing device specific pricing for products using Googles IAB

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-play

Looking at Google's IAB API it's pretty clear you cannot access pricing information for the products.  Clearly this is problematic if I have multiple products I'm showing to a user.

I'm wondering what other Android developers have done with regards to creating a store front activity.  It seems like there's three options.

1. Show your list of products without prices, forcing the user to click on each to bring up the purchase Activity with the price visible.
2. Pick a currency (say USD) and just show the price in that, knowing you'll likely annoy users not from the US.
3. Attempt to guess the users currency based on their locale or location and look up a 'best guess' price from a table you maintain someone where.

I'd love to hear which options people chose and why.  It's really ming boggling that Google doesn't give you access to this information so you can display a proper menu of products to buy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has resolved this with the release of 'In-App Billing Version 3', which supports querying for product information (including price).

Answer (score 0):

> Pick a currency (say USD) and just show the price in that, knowing you'll likely annoy users not from the US.

I think you answered yourself. This is not a great user experience.

> Attempt to guess the users currency based on their locale or location and look up a 'best guess' price from a table you maintain someone where.

If you absolutely require to show prices to the user before sending them to Google Play, then this is the best option available.

> It's really ming boggling that Google doesn't give you access to this
>   information so you can display a proper menu of products to buy.

There's [Google Play Android Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/v1/) and this look like a feature that could be added to it. Tell Google you'd like to see this feature added, not us. :)

Answer (score 0):

So sharing what I ended up using as a solution/workaround in case others face this same question.

Instead of showing prices I have the least Expensive item label with the translated string 'BUY'.  The other items I have listed as %discount.

So the store reads like this

- 5X number of widgets   80% discount
- 3X number of widgets   66% discount
- X number of widgets    BUY

I thinks it's a little shady not to list total price, but since I can't, at least these works around the issue of what to display.